# [Powershell/Sharepoint]Can someone review my script to delete Sharepoint list items older than 7 days? Getting'Cannot index into Null Array'

Tags: arrays, powershell, sharepoint, scripting

Script I made deletes items older than 7 days in each folder called Scans.
It will delete then eventually error out with 'Cannot index into a null array.'

Can someone help me with whats wrong with my script or if there is a better way to do it?

```
   foreach ($site in $opsSite)
    {
        Write-Host $site.Title;
        $oList = $site.Lists["Scans"];


        foreach ($list in $Lists)
            {
                $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
                $Query.Query = "@
                    <Where>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                             <Value Type='DateTime'>
                                [Today-7Day(s)]
                             </Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </Where>"
                #Get List Items matching the query
                $ListItems = $oList.GetItems($Query)
                $collListItems = $oList.Items;
                $count = $collListItems.Count;

                        for($intIndex = 0; $intIndex -lt $count; $intIndex++)
                            {
                                $listItem = $collListItems[$intIndex];
                                foreach ($Item in $Items)
                                {
                                    write-host "Deleting" + $listItem.Name + $listItem["Created"];
                                    $collListItems.Delete($intIndex);
                                }
                            }
            }
```

Comment: comment me after you add the following to your question: Add an example of: items in each folder called Scans. If your items are files in the current folder and its sub-folders you can do it with one line. Give me some idea of your directory structure. Where do the files start, where do they end?

Comment: do check your query also why you have two object for all item one with query and one without query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please build your query like this:

```
 <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='Created' />
         <Value Type='DateTime'>
            <Today Offset='-7' />
         </Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
```

You could try the following code to delete items older than 7 days:

```
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$Query.Query = "@
          <Where>
           <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
             <Value Type='DateTime'>
               <Today Offset='-7' />
             </Value>
           </Eq>
          </Where>"
#Get List Items matching the query
$ListItems = $oList.GetItems($Query)
foreach($ListItem in $ListItems){
    write-host "Deleting" + $listItem.Name + $listItem["Created"];
    $ListItem.delete()
}
```

Update:

Change yor query to this:

```
<Where>
      <Lt>
         <FieldRef Name='Created' />
         <Value Type='DateTime'>
            <Today Offset='-7' />
         </Value>
      </Lt>
   </Where>
```

The code:

```
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$Query.Query = "@
          <Where>
           <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
             <Value Type='DateTime'>
               <Today Offset='-7' />
             </Value>
           </Lt>
          </Where>"
#Get List Items matching the query
$ListItems = $oList.GetItems($Query)
foreach($ListItem in $ListItems){
    write-host "Deleting" + $listItem.Name + $listItem["Created"];
    $ListItem.delete()
}
```

Comment: Hey Michael, I copied your code and it is still returning items in the 7 day range. Im on a sharpoint 2010 environment btw.

Comment: My mistake. The query will retrun items when created = today -7. I have updated my answer.. Please check if it works.

Comment: Thank you Michael! You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't delete using Foreach loop.you can't modify the collection again.
try using this

```
for($intIndex = 0; $intIndex -lt $count; $intIndex++){
  $listItem = $collListItems[$intIndex];
  write-host "Deleting" + $listItem.Name + $listItem["Created"];
  $collListItems[$intIndex].Delete();// it will delete from recyle bin too,better to use recycle method}
```